# Unit of measurement between two CGPoints

Tags: ios

How to determine unit of measurement between two CGPoint's. I basically want to convert distance between two CGPoints in centi meter and milli meter. I cannot find in any docs to implement correctly.

```
 CGFloat xDist = point2.x - point1.x;
 CGFloat yDist = point2.y - point1.y;
 CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to correlate a device's physical screen size to the number of points on the screen.

You also have to realize that pixels (and points) aren't square. So you need both horizontal and vertical values.

Your only (bad) option is to hardcode values for every known iOS device and update your app every time a new device comes out.

Comment: can you give me example for iPhone 5 & 6.. I mean  example with hardcorded value ... I cant find info about this.. Thanks

Comment: Let's assume. distance is 50. Now how do i convert it to cm or mm.... hardcorded approach is fine.. Any link to know about this will be helpful too ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices From there you can find physical screen dimensions.

Comment: I thought that point sizes were either one or two pixels across in either dimension?

Comment: @Braains This has nothing to do with points vs pixels. It has to do with pixels (or points) per physical screen dimension. You can't simply draw a line 20 points (for example) and expect it to measure the same physical length on every iOS device. Key example - all iPads are 1024x768 points in size but the iPad minis are obviously physically smaller than regular iPads.

Comment: Oh now I'm following. Thanks for the explanation